# Denormalized schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, relayjs, graphql-js

Mongoose schema:

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    content: { type: String },

    comments: {
        count: { type: Number },
        data: [{
            author: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            },
            content: { type: String },
            created: { type: Date },

            replies: [{
                author: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'User'
                },
                content: { type: String },
                created: { type: Date },
            }]
        }]
    }
})
```

---

I don't want to normalize comments and replies because:

- I will always need post comments together (*read in a single go*)
- I will never use comments to query or sort anything
- It's so much easier to create, update and delete post with comments (*document locking*)

---

If I normalized it, I would have to:

- Get post from database
- Get comments from database
- Get replies for **each** comment

---

This is one of the biggest strengths of MongoDB: to group your data specifically to suit your application data needs but GraphQL and Relay.js doesn't seem to support that?

**Question:**

Is there a way to get comments nested inside of a single post object (or at least get replies nested inside of a single comment) in order to get the whole thing in a single read?

---

GraphQL schema:

```
const postType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Post',
    fields: () => ({
        id: globalIdField('Post'),
        title: { type: GraphQLString },
        content: { type: GraphQLString },

        comments: {

            // ?????

        }
    }),
    interfaces: [nodeInterface],
})
```

---

### **Update:**

```
const postType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Post',
    fields: () => ({
        id: globalIdField('Post'),
        title: { type: GraphQLString },
        content: { type: GraphQLString },

        commentCount: { type: GraphQLInt },
        comments: { type: new GraphQLList(commentType) }
    }),
    interfaces: [nodeInterface]
})
```

---

```
const commentType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Comment',
    fields: () => ({
        content: { type: GraphQLString },
        created: { type: GraphQLString },
        author: {
            type: userType,
            resolve: async (comment) => {
                return await getUserById(comment.author)
            }
        },
        replies: {
            type: new GraphQLList(commentType),
            resolve: (comment) => {

                // Log is below
                console.log(comment)

                // Error only occurs if I return it!
                return comment.replies
            }
        }
    })
})
```

---

Log (`comment`):

```
{ 
  author: 'user-1',
  created: '05:35'
  content: 'Wow, this is an awesome comment!',
  replies:
     [{ 
       author: 'user-2',
       created: '11:01',
       content: 'Not really..',
     },
     {  
       author: 'user-1',
       created: '11:03',
       content: 'Why are you so salty?',
     }]
}
```

Comment: Make 'comments' array of objects, so that you can access it easily using one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is one of the biggest strengths of MongoDB: to group your data specifically to suit your application data needs but GraphQL and Relay.js doesn't seem to support that?

GraphQL does support what you're trying to do. Before going into the details, we need to keep in mind that GraphQL is about exposing data, NOT about how we store data. We can store in whatever way we like - normalized or not. We just need to tell GraphQL how to get the data that we define in the GraphQL schema.

> Is there a way to get comments nested inside of a single post object (or at least get replies nested inside of a single comment) in order to get the whole thing in a single read?

Yes, it's possible. You just define the comments as a list. However, GraphQL does not support arbitrary type of field in a GraphQL object type. Therefore, we need to define separate GraphQL types. In your mongoose schema, `comments` is an object with `count` of comments and the comments `data`. The `data` property is a list of another type of objects. So, we need to define two GraphQL objects - `Comment` and `CommentList`. The code looks like below:

```
const commentType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Comment',
  fields: () => ({
    author: { type: GraphQLString },
    content: { type: GraphQLString },
    created: { type: GraphQLString },
    replies: { type: new GraphQLList(commentType) },
  }),
});

const commentListType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'CommentList',
  fields: () => ({
    count: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      resolve: (comments) => comments.length,
    },
    data: {
      type: new GraphQLList(commentType),
      resolve: (comments) => comments,
    },
  }),
});

const postType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Post',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('Post'),
    title: { type: GraphQLString },
    content: { type: GraphQLString },

    comments: {
      type: commentListType,
      resolve: (post) => post.comments,
    }
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});
```

> I don't want to normalize comments and replies because:
>
> - I will always need post comments together (read in a single go)
> - I will never use comments to query or sort anything
> - It's so much easier to create, update and delete post with comments (document locking)

Defining post and comment GraphQL object types in the above way let you:

- read all post comments together
- not to use comment to query, as it does not even have `id` field.
- implement comments manipulation in whatever way you like with your preferred database. GraphQL has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Any idea why I get error `User Error: expected iterable, but did not find one for field Comment.replies.`?

Comment: Did you check replies for `null`? A comment may not have any reply. In that case, depending on your implementation, `replies` can be either `null` or an empty array. Empty array in case of no reply is better IMHO, because it avoids the need to check for `null`.

Comment: Replies are either populated or an empty array.. Still not sure what's the problem ..

Comment: How does your resolve function for `comment.replies` look like?

Comment: Only `type: new GraphQLList(commentType)` because names match. I've also tried `resolve: (comment) => comment.replies` but still same error.

Comment: To debug the problem, you can add a resolve function for `replies` field and check what you actually get in server-side object's `replies` field before returning the reply list.

Comment: Replace `return comment.replies` with `return comment.replies ? comment.replies : [];`. Your log shows that `replies` didn't have `replies` data in it. Remember, replies are also comments.

Comment: I checked `comment.replies.constructor === Array` and it returns **false**.. Something goes very wrong between GraphQL and MongoDB if I try to nest list of objects in object. (_a.la_ `commentType-s` in `commentType`). Problem is probably in MongoDB `date` and `id` type, it's not string nor pure number, GraphQL doesn't convert it if it's nested and it breaks GraphQL list (array).

Comment: Did you implement as this answer suggests?

Comment: and one more thing. Your question is about how you can model the nested list in the Mongoose schema you mentioned with GraphQL. Does this post answer your question? I implemented and tested this solution with some hard-coded posts, comments and replies. It works. You're now talking about a different problem actually, which has more to do with your server-side object (MongoDB doc) to GraphQL object translation.